# Giving a user access to a new database you don't have access to

Tags: sql-server

I have a scenario where I have a SQL Server login (let's call it myuser) with the following roles: dbcreator and securityadmin. That user has access to a single database and needs to create other databases and create more logins and give users access to the new databases. Code would look something like this:

```
RESTORE DATABASE MYDB FROM DISK='c:\\mybackup.bak'
WITH MOVE 'MYDB_Data' TO 'C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SQL Server\\MSSQL11.SQLEXPRESS\\MSSQL\\DATA\\MYDB.mdf',
     MOVE 'MYDB_Log' TO 'C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SQL Server\\MSSQL11.SQLEXPRESS\\MSSQL\\DATA\\MYDB_log.ldf'
GO

CREATE LOGIN mydb_user WITH PASSWORD = '123'
GO

USE MYDB
CREATE USER [mydb_user] FOR LOGIN [mydb_user]
EXEC sp_addrolemember N'db_owner', N'mydb_user'
```

Problem I'm running into is that the "USE MYDB" statement fails because myuser doesn't have access to MYDB. Technically, I don't need myuser to have access to any data, I just need it to be able to create the user and add the tole to the DB, but not sure if that can be achieved without access to the DB itself. And if access to the DB is required to give access to other users, how would I go about giving it. I would think that if the user actually created the DB, he should be able to grant himself access to it?

Comment: When the DB is restored, who is the owner of the DB? I think when a user [myuser] creates a DB with dbcreator role, that database's owner should be [myuser].

Comment: @ArthurD Yes, appears so, and yet the user still doesn't seem to have access to the database, which I find a bit puzzling.